# Extra line shown in UILabel Swift-3

Tags: ios, uilabel, swift3

I am setting uilabel layer cornerRadius and sometimes the label has extra line in some corners / edges of the label , is there a way to avoid this ?

Please find below the screen shot .

[image]

code :

```
//Message view
        let messageLabel = UILabel()
        messageLabel.backgroundColor = #someColor
        messageLabel.textColor = #someColor
        messageLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14)
        messageLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byWordWrapping
        messageLabel.attributedText = attributedString
        messageLabel.numberOfLines = 0
        messageLabel.textAlignment = .center
        messageLabel.shadowColor = UIColor.clear
        messageLabel.layer.cornerRadius = 3.0

        let maskPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: messageLabel.bounds,
                                    byRoundingCorners: [.topLeft, .topRight, .bottomRight],
                                    cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 18.0, height: 0.0))
        let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        maskLayer.path = maskPath.cgPath
        messageLabel.layer.mask = maskLayer
```

Comment: The second label in the screen shot has an extra line on the top edge

Comment: You mean the thin dark line on the top border of the label, at the boundary between the white and the gray? (I see a little on the right side as well.)

Comment: yes , and it doesn happen to all the uilables which I add the same way , sometimes , there is no border at all , sometimes the border is shown in a different edge , I tried setting the border color clear , messageLabel.layer.borderColor = UIColor.clear.cgcolor

Comment: @VinodhaSundaramoorthy How are you setting `messageLabel` frame? Perhaps there are some fractional values there?

Comment: The frame is set by dynamically calculating the size of string for a particular font and size.Let me try rounding the values

Comment: @alexburtnik : yes , after using ceil(width) , ceil(height) , not seeing the border , if you can post it as an answer , I will accept it.Thanks for the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These kind of issues may happen if `frame` has fractional `x`/`y`/`width`/`height` values.

If this is your case, try to round all values with one of these functions: `round()`, `ceil()` or `floor()`